# innerHTML appends data as string instead of event in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I've been trying to call a function when the page loads:
here's the html side:

`<div id='mapid'></div>`

and here's my javascript code:

```
var output2='onload="myVar = setTimeout(mapAll, 1)"';
document.getElementById("mapid").innerHTML += output2
```

However, instead of executing the function, I get a plain text on the screen saying "'onload="myVar = setTimeout(mapAll, 1)"'"

So, is there a way to fix this and at the same time keep the id for later use so that I would get something like this:
`<div id="mapid" onload="myVar = setTimeout(mapAll, 1)"></div>`

Comment: innerHTML is not where you put elements attributes

Comment: The *innerHTML* property represents an element's markup, so you're doing the equivalent of `<div id='mapid'>onload="myVar = setTimeout(mapAll, 1)"</div>`. How would you expect that to be parsed and displayed?

Comment: Assuming you get the event binding to work, what is the purpose of the timeout?

Comment: The onload part is outerHTML, not inner. You can just use element.onload = function if you don't need to change the markup

Answer (score 1):

Use `setAttribute` instead of `innerHTML`.

You can do like this if you want to add inline event handler

```
document.getElementById("mapid").setAttribute('onload', myFunction());

function myFunction() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    //rest of the code
  }, 2000);
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/277gpp7r/5/)

Comment: This will call `myFunction()` *immediately* and then try to set its return value (`undefined`) as the `onload` attribute. So it *seems* to work, but really it doesn't because the `onload` part isn't doing what it should.